# Middle function on python

Tags: python

Write a function middle which takes a list L as its argument, and returns   the item in the middle  position of L, when L has an odd length. Otherwise, middle should return 999999. For example, calling middle([8, 0, 100, 12, 1]) should return  100.

this is what I has so far:

```
def middle(L):
    '''(str) -> str
    takes L and returns the middle number of the function and if it isnt
    odd length it returns 999999

    >>> middle([6, 3 , 8, 34, 56])
    8
    >>> middle([16, 23, 14, 22, 99,])
    999999
    >>> middle([1038, 2732, 29232, 2342, 7565])
    29232
    '''
    def middle (L):
        L= len(0:-1])/2
    return L
print (middle)
```

Comment: So show your own attempts for this homework.

Answer (score 2):

```
def myfunc(mylist):
    if len(mylist) % 2 == 0:
        return 999999
    return mylist[(len(mylist)-1)//2]
```

Comment: The `else` clause is redundant if the `if` block ends with a `return` inside a function, or with an `exit` outside a function. One may as well just remove the `else` line and remove one level of indentation of its block.

Comment: Also note in Python3 this will fail. You need to use the _true_ division operator, `//`, to get an integer value, instead of a floating point one.

Comment: @PauloScardine The Else part of the statement might be more understandable for OP who is obviously new to the language - but I prefer your more succinct version

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution (works for CS Circles).

The // is integer division without a remainder.

```
def middle(L):
   return L[len(L)//2]
```